# How to access index when mapping an enumerated list using a non-lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, enumerate

I'm mapping over an enumerated list and I'd like to access the index value when I'm **not** using a lambda function.

For example, I can access index values when using lambda like so:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

map(lambda (i, v): { i: v }, enumerate(arr))
```

But I can't do the same when not using lambda:

```
map(parser, enumerate(arr))

def parser(i, v):
    return { i : v }
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: parser() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Why is this the case??

Comment: Heads up: Tuple unpacking in argument lists has been removed in newer versions of python.

Comment: Use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead

Comment: And you can do that with `def` functions (`def f((x, y))`), too. `lambda (x, y): ...` != `lambda x, y: ...`. Your `def` function is equivalent to the latter. And, as pointed out by @Aran-Fey, this feature has been removed in Py3.